# compressing vector into comma seperated string

Tags: r, dplyr

How can I compress the results of `unique` into a comma delimited string?

```
temp3 <- data.frame(categoryId=c(1,1,1,2),ballot1=c("yes","yes","no","200"))
temp3 %>% group_by(categoryId)
      %>% mutate(responses=unique(ballot1))
```

***Expected Output:***

```
1 yes,no
1 yes,no
1 yes,no
2 200
```

Comment: You want each row to have a different number of columns? That's not really a data frame any more. What do you really need?

Comment: Good point, I will edit my question to stick within the dataframe structure

Answer (score 1):

We can group by 'categoryId', get the `unique` elements in 'ballot1' and `paste` them together

```
library(dplyr) 
temp3 %>% 
   group_by(categoryId) %>%
   mutate(ballot1 = toString(unique(ballot1)))
# A tibble: 4 x 2
# Groups:   categoryId [2]
#   categoryId ballot1
#       <dbl>   <chr>
#1          1 yes, no
#2          1 yes, no
#3          1 yes, no
#4          2     200
```